# Joomla iCal Function

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, module, icalendar

For some reason this Joomla 'Jevents' module is using an iCal format to display start date / end date which makes it seem encrypted. `1339246800` This is an encrypted start date for the month of June and I was wondering if anyone knew the function to decrypt said start date. I am pulling these values from a database and would like to show them as simple 'Month - Day' format. I tried to ask the Jevents forums but I'm not getting anywhere fast. Here's the [Link](http://www.jevents.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=14508)

Comment: That's a Unix time stamp, the number of seconds since January 1, 1970. You can convert it to a normal date using the `date()` function http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does appear to be a unix timestamp, and if you're pulling it from the database, you can use FROM_UNIXTIME() like this:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1339246800,'%M %d');
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(YouriCalDateColumn,'%M %d') FROM yourTable
```

If that doesn't return the right date, then provide the date you're expecting ,and the number that it's stored as, and we can have a closer look.